# ASP page not running JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp-classic

I am trying to add some JavaScript/JQuery into an ASP page made by my predecessor at work, but for some reason it is not running at all. When I check the script console in IE dev tools, it says "SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier" on the fifth JavaScript line below (not including the tags), but I can't see what the issue is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dynamicregisterbutton").hover(mEnter, mLeave);      
});
function mEnter(){
    $.("#dynamicloginbutton").stop(false,true).hide(200);
    $.("#dynamicregisterbutton").stop(false,true).animate({width:'220px'},{duration:300, queue:false});
    $.("#dynamicregisterbutton").stop(false,true).animate({height:'80px'},{duration:300, queue:false}); 
}
function mLeave(){
    $.("#dynamicloginbutton").stop(false,true).show(200);
    $.("#dynamicregisterbutton").stop(false,true).animate({width:"100px"},{duration:300, queue:false});
    $.("#dynamicregisterbutton").stop(false,true).animate({height:"32px"},{duration:300, queue:false}); 
}
</script>
```

I am using the below script tag to link to the JQuery library;

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As far as I can tell from reading around there shouldn't be any issue running JavaScript inside of ASP files, and I am sure I have done it at some point before. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The first question is of course, are you sure the jQuery lib is loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I am using one of the google links. I'll add that to me post.

Comment: You have an extra `.` between the `$` and selector in the `mLeave()` and 1mEnter` functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing all your codes like:

```
$.("#dynamicloginbutton")    // Error in `$.()`
```

to a valid jQuery code like:

```
$("#dynamicloginbutton")     // just `$()`
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `.` character in the selectors. Try this:

```
function mEnter(){
    $("#dynamicloginbutton").stop(false,true).hide(200);
    $("#dynamicregisterbutton").stop(false,true).animate({width:'220px'},{duration:300, queue:false});
    $("#dynamicregisterbutton").stop(false,true).animate({height:'80px'},{duration:300, queue:false}); 
}
function mLeave(){
    $("#dynamicloginbutton").stop(false,true).show(200);
    $("#dynamicregisterbutton").stop(false,true).animate({width:"100px"},{duration:300, queue:false});
    $("#dynamicregisterbutton").stop(false,true).animate({height:"32px"},{duration:300, queue:false}); 
}
```